# NVP request - CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

Im facing problem with Trail period and first month payemnt.
My requirement is users can signup with trial period 
which allow new users to have a 30 day free trial. 
This means they will not be charged the monthly price until after the first 30 days
the  regular amount will be charged to user. but the next billing date should be one month 
later the profile start date. but next billing data and profile start date shows same when 
i query by GetRecurringPaymentProfile?

Please help me how can i send the Recurring bill payment for this functionality.

Thanks in advance,

jiwan

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the following variables:

```
TRIALBILLINGPERIOD=Day
TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY=30
TRIALAMT=0.00
```

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments